# java.net.UnknownHostException cannot be cast to retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am getting this error in my logs:

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.UnknownHostException cannot be cast to retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException
```

and thats my onError method. The error is probably caused when the device has no connection.

```
  @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            assert e != null;
            Timber.d(e);
            HttpException exception = (HttpException) e;
            assert view != null;
            view.hideRefreshSpinner();
            if (exception.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
                view.showSnackbarInvalidError();
            } else {
                view.showUnauthorizedError();
            }

        }
```

Comment: put your host address

Comment: The host address is valid, it just I think when the call is made there is a network but no real connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because you're receiving an instance of `java.net.UnknownHostException` and not `retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException`. If you look at the [doc](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava2/RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.java), it says:

> - Direct body (e.g., Observable) calls onNext with the deserialized body for 2XX responses and calls onError with
>     HttpException for non-2XX responses and **IOException for network
>     errors**.
> - Response wrapped body (e.g., Observable>) calls onNext with a Response object for all HTTP responses and calls onError
>     with IOException for network errors
> - Result wrapped body (e.g., Observable>) calls onNext with a Result object for all HTTP responses and errors.

So you are receiving a network error.

Also see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)

You can wrap your code like this:

```
@Override
public void onError(Throwable e) {
    assert e != null;
    Timber.d(e);
    if (e instanceof HttpException) {
        assert view != null;
        view.hideRefreshSpinner();
        if (((HttpException) e).code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
            view.showSnackbarInvalidError();
        } else {
            view.showUnauthorizedError();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try it and come back with results.